# Django redirect within method

Tags: django, redirect

I have the following:

```
def wiki(request,title):
    entries = []
    entry = util.get_entry(title)
    if entry != None:
        markdowner = Markdown()
        entry = markdowner.convert(entry)
        entries.append(entry)

    return render(request, "encyclopedia/entry.html", {
        "title": title,
        "entries": entries,
    })

def search(request):

    search=request.GET.get('q')
    entries = util.list_entries()

    for entry in entries:
    
        if search == entry:
    #########################################
            entries = []
            entry = util.get_entry(search)
            markdowner = Markdown()
            entry = markdowner.convert(entry)
            entries.append(entry)
            return render(request, "encyclopedia/entry.html", {
                "title": search,
                "entries": entries,
            })
     #######################################

    possible=( [str for str in entries if
        (search in str )] )
    print(possible)
    return render(request, "encyclopedia/search.html")
```

if search == entry: is there some way to redirect to or call wiki(request,title)?
and thereby be able to eliminate the code between the hash marks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can let Django resolve the url and redirect properly:

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect

def search(request):
    search = request.GET.get('q')
    entries = util.list_entries()

    for entry in entries:
        if search == entry:
            return redirect(wiki, title=search)

    possible=( [str for str in entries if
        (search in str )] )
    print(possible)
    return render(request, 'encyclopedia/search.html')
```

Comment: this is great, thank you.  Can you explain what request is in def wiki(request,title) and why I don't seem to need it when I call the redirect?

Comment: @DCR: by using `redirect`, you return a 302 HTTP response, and the client makes a new request. For URL resolution, you never pass the request, since that is not part of the URL.